# How to send a data to one Javascript script file to another Javascript script file

Tags: javascript, frontend

I want to send a = 5 to another js file and add them,the other file should have a type = "module" in it.

```
<script>
  let a = 5;
  // file 1
</script>
    
<script type="module">
  console.log(a+5)
  // file 2
  // I need (type = "module") in file 2
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because modules run and load asynchronously, the non-module script will run first, which will make things a bit difficult. I'd put the non-module script in a separate file - this will allow you to use the `defer` attribute on its script tag (`defer` has no effect on inline scripts). Since deferred scripts run in the order in which they appear in the DOM, you can then have the module expose something globally, first, and then have the deferred non-module call that global function.

```
<script src="file-2.js" type="module"></script>
<script defer src="file-1.js"></script>
```

```
// file-2.js
window.doSomethingWithA = (a) => {
  console.log(a);
}
```

```
// file-1.js
window.doSomethingWithA(5);
```

But a better approach would be to put *all* your scripts into modules - it'll make things a lot easier to manage when the code becomes of any reasonable size. It's also counter-productive for a module to make something global - one of the big selling points of modules is that they can be made to be completely self-contained.

Another approach, without relying on script order, would be to have the non-module script listen for a `load` event on the module script, then call the global function.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer assume both the files are in the same folder:

```
Folder
   |- firstFile.js
   |- secondFile.js
```

add `export` in firstFile.js

```
//firstFile.js
export let a = 5;
```

and `import` in secondFile.js

```
//secondFile.js
import {a} from './firstFile.js'
console.log(a)

result:
5
```